# An uncaught error was detected outside of a test

Tags: cypress, uncaught-exception, cypress-component-test-runner

When I run all my component cypress tests locally on a Macbook pro on a react-vite project with around ~10 tests, I get the following error:

```
An uncaught error was detected outside of a test:
     TypeError: The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:5173/__cypress/src/cypress/support/component.ts

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.
```

the error is not Consistant and doesn't show up on every run. It also throws on a random test every run. How can I solve this?

**update**: I think a possible lead could be that I import files on my project with the absolute paths pattern.
For example:

```
import {comp1, comp2} from 'components'
```

where as `components` is configured in my `tsconfig.ts` file

Comment: Is there any `import "cypress"` got added at the top of your test file? If so, remove it.

Comment: there isn't an import at the top of any file

Answer (score 0):

ok so after countless attempts to fix this and also encountering terminal freezes when I execute
`cypress run`.
I've gave up and created a bash script to run each of the tests in the code base separately:

```
set -x
#!/bin/bash

for file in $( find . -type f -name '*.spec.cy.tsx' );
    do yarn cypress run --component --browser chrome --spec $file || exit 1
done
```

for now it seems to get the job done. Hope this helps anyone else that encounters this